# Why won't the input tag populate in other columns?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, datatables, javascript-objects

I'm trying to use a loop to create a table row with 7 table cells. Each cell containing information from js objects and an input box next to these values. When I run the HTML file, I get empty cells not containing the  tags.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grades">
        <table id="inventory">
            <div class="tableHeader">
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>PUG</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>PUB</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>NP</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
               
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var products = [phoneOne, phoneTwo, phoneThree, phoneFour];

function populateItems(i){
    var inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");
    var insertRow = inventory.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = insertRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = insertRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = insertRow.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = insertRow.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = insertRow.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = insertRow.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = insertRow.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = insertRow.insertCell(7);
    var inputBox = document.createElement("input");

    cell1.textContent = products[i].modelName;
    cell2.textContent = products[i].pug;
    cell3.appendChild(inputBox);
    cell4.textContent = products[i].pub;
    cell5.appendChild(inputBox);
    cell6.textContent = products[i].pub;
    cell7.appendChild(inputBox);   
    cell8.appendChild(inputBox);
}
for (i=0; i<products.length; i++){
    populateItems(i);
}
```

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgNoy.jpg)

Comment: you create a single inputBox ... appending it to multiple places simply moves it - try `.appendChild(inputBox.cloneNode());`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Inventory</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grades">
            <table id="inventory"> <!--removed div-->
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>PUG</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>PUB</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>NP</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                </tr> <!--added-->
                
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="populate-table.js"></script>  <!--added-->
</html>
```

JS: (populate-table.js)

```
var products = [ {modelName: 'iPhone4',
                  pug: 72,    
                  pub: 86,
                  np: 86
                 },
                 {modelName: 'iPhone3',
                  pug: 42,    
                  pub: 30,
                  np: 30
                 },
                 {modelName: 'iPhone2',
                  pug: 85,    
                  pub: 12,
                  np: 12
                 },
                 {modelName: 'iPhone1',
                 pug: 53,    
                 pub: 32,
                 np: 32
                },
               ]

function populateItems(i){
    var inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");
    var insertRow = inventory.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = insertRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = insertRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = insertRow.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = insertRow.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = insertRow.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = insertRow.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = insertRow.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = insertRow.insertCell(7);
    var inputBox1 = document.createElement("input");
    inputBox1.style.width = "8ch";
    var inputBox2 = document.createElement("input");
    inputBox2.style.width = "8ch";
    var inputBox3 = document.createElement("input");
    inputBox3.style.width = "8ch";
    var inputBox4 = document.createElement("input");
    inputBox4.style.width = "28ch";
    cell1.textContent = products[i].modelName;
    cell2.textContent = products[i].pug;
    cell3.appendChild(inputBox1);
    cell4.textContent = products[i].pub;
    cell5.appendChild(inputBox2);
    cell6.textContent = products[i].np;
    cell7.appendChild(inputBox3);   
    cell8.appendChild(inputBox4);
}
for (i=0; i<products.length; i++){
    populateItems(i);
}
```